# WebClient.OpenReadAsync() corrupts JSON data. Why?

Tags: c#, silverlight, webclient, corrupt-data

I have a class in my Silverlight app that (de-)serializes JSON strings to/from an object class.
I use `WebClient.OpenReadAsync` to get a file that contains this JSON string:

```
{"FirstName":"Bob","LastName":"Underwood"}
```

After calling `OpenReadAsync` however, the retrieved string has a lot of extra characters:

```
"PK\n\0\0\0\0\0�u�>h��5\0\0\05\0\0\0\t\0\0\0test.json\"{\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"Gary\\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"MacDonald\\\"}\"PK\0\n\0\0\0\0\0�u�>h��5\0\0\05\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0test.jsonPK\0\0\0\0\0\07\0\0\0\\\0\0\0\0\0"
```

This is the code I'm using to download the JSON:

```cs
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("/someJsonFile.zip", UriKind.Relative));

void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Error == null) {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result);
        string jsonString =  reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
    }
    else {
        addMessage("Error " + e.Error.ToString());
    }
}
```

`jsonString` ends up with all that extra data, so I can't deserialize it as is.

Another thing to note: the URI points to `someJsonFile.zip`, but it's really not zipped, when I give the file a extension like `.json`, or no extension, I get a error that it cannot find the file, but when I give it a extension like `.zip`, it finds it fine. Is there a way I can use a normal or no extension? I was wondering if this was a configuration issue.

**Questions:**

1. Am I doing something wrong in pulling this file and using `StreamReader` to get the string that's causing me to get all that trash data?
2. Do I need to do something specific to be able to use `WebClient` to grab a file with different extensions, like `.json`, or even no extension at all?

Comment: All of these problems come from your web server.

Comment: …except that you are not doing a `reader.Dispose()` anywhere! You should put it inside a `using` block, e.g.: `using (StreamReader reader = …) { … }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - That data stream certainly is a ZIP (`PK` is the old PKZip marker and the test.json filename is mentioned in its index as well).

Your server may be setup to serve all files compressed (or you may simply be accessing an actual zip file). Please check the server settings.

2 - As for the second question, the WebClient does not care about file types. It is just a stream of data that needs to be interpreted by something that knows what the data is (i.e. your code).

It is only the server that may be configured to serve up different files in different ways.

Comment: I'll have a look, I know for sure it's a text file i uploaded, because I renamed it from test.json to test.zip, then changed the uri in code to reflect .zip instead of .json just to test if it would work, and it did. I also tried no extension, so far only renaing it to .zip worked. I don't actually mind just zipping the file, just wanted to understand if the extension mattered, i'll ask my provider if they have anything setup for that.  That was a good tip the server may be setup to serve all files compressed, this may very well be it. I'll have a look, thanks for the direction.

Comment: Well I zipped my file, and after retrieving it with webclient and unzipping it, I get: "\"\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"Gary\\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"MacDonald\\\"}\""
This is better than before, but still has a lot of additional slashes. I've put a ticket in to my domain to see if there should be any problems with what i'm doing and their configuration.

Comment: Q: Why are you using a .zip extension in the first place if you do not want it to be a zip file?

Comment: I explained that above, I was having problems getting the file to download, so I tried that as a test, since .zip files are usually considered safe to download. the .Zip extension or a real .zip file do download fine, i've not been able to get anything else to download, comes back with can't find the file.

Comment: If you can only download files with a Zip extension, you have more serious problems than just the above :) Please do post the results of your investigation with your IT bods.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure things out with my domain provider, appears to have been some configuration issues on their end.